# Issues with colspan in CSS table

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'm trying to achieve a table where the first column is twice as long as the remaining two columns. When I apply `colspan=2` to the table it does nothing

Code in action

http://jsfiddle.net/US96B/

Raw code below

```
<div class="datagrid">
    <table>';
        <thead><tr><th colspan="2">header</th><th>header</th><th>header</th></tr></thead>
        <tfoot><tr><td colspan="4"><div id="no-paging">&nbsp;</div></tr></tfoot>
        <tbody>
            <tr><td colspan="2">data</td><td>data</td><td>data</td></tr>
            <tr><td colspan="2">data</td><td>data</td><td>data</td></tr>
            <tr><td colspan="2">data</td><td>data</td><td>data</td></tr>
            <tr><td colspan="2">data</td><td>data</td><td>data</td></tr>
            <tr><td colspan="2">data</td><td>data</td><td>data</td></tr>
            <tr><td colspan="2">data</td><td>data</td><td>data</td></tr>
            <tr><td colspan="2">data</td><td>data</td><td>data</td></tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

The CSS

```
.datagrid table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    text-align: left;
    width: 100%;
}
.datagrid {
    font: normal 12px/150% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background: #fff;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid #5492A2;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
}
.datagrid table td,
.datagrid table th {
    padding: 10px 0px;
}
.datagrid table thead th {
    background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #288096), color-stop(1, #288096) );
    background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #288096 5%, #288096 100% );
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#288096', endColorstr='#288096');
    background-color:#288096;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-left: 1px solid #0070A8;
}
.datagrid table thead th:first-child {
    border: none;
}
.datagrid table tbody td {
    color: #D4D2D2;
    border-left: 1px solid #D4D2D2;
    font-size: 16px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #E1EEF4;
    font-weight: normal;
}
.datagrid table tbody td:first-child {
    border-left: none;
}
.datagrid table tbody tr:last-child td {
    border-bottom: none;
}
.datagrid table tfoot td div {
    border-top: 1px solid #5492A2;
    background: #FFFFFF;
}
.datagrid table tfoot td {
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 18px
}
.datagrid table tfoot td div {
    padding: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It actually is working. But since they ALL are `colspan`ing you cannot tell.

Here is my fiddle showing you that the `colspan` is working (the first row in `tbody` I set to 4 columns, with no spans). If you are trying to achieve to "look" of the first 2 spanning together you can adjust the widths like I did in my Fiddle (50% / 25% / 25%)

http://jsfiddle.net/doitlikejustin/US96B/4/

Answer (score 3):

`colspan` is not used to specify the `width` of columns as you did. This is used to show particular `cell` spanned into multiple `columns`. But in your case `colspan` should not be used. Instead you can use `width` as 50% for 1st column and 25% for other two cols.

But if you want to use `colspan`, the following way will work.

```
<div class="datagrid">
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th colspan="2" width="25%">header</th>
                <th width="25%"></th>
                <th>header</th>
                <th>header</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr><td colspan="2">data</td><td></td><td>data</td><td>data</td></tr>
            <tr><td colspan="2">data</td><td></td><td>data</td><td>data</td></tr>
            <tr><td colspan="2">data</td><td></td><td>data</td><td>data</td></tr>
            <tr><td colspan="2">data</td><td></td><td>data</td><td>data</td></tr>
            <tr><td colspan="2">data</td><td></td><td>data</td><td>data</td></tr>
            <tr><td colspan="2">data</td><td></td><td>data</td><td>data</td></tr>
            <tr><td colspan="2">data</td><td></td><td>data</td><td>data</td></tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: The use of `colspan` is even invalid here: it violates the HTML table model, as one can see by validating the code as HTML5. (HTML5 validation checks such things.)

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela I know that this is not valid. But this code os added just to show how colspan can be used to get the desired result.

Comment: The examples here use percentages because using actual width in pixels simply does not work as expected. If 1 want my column to be 100 pixels wide I have to change more than 1 line of code to make it happen. i.e. css is badly implemented in this area.

Answer (score 1):

What about specifying `width="50%"` in the first `<th>` and `width="25%"` in the other two?  No need for `colspan` at all.

Answer (score 0):

I have updated your fiddle and it is working as intended now.

**[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Xandour/US96B/5/)**

```
.datagrid table thead th:first-child {
    border: none;
    width:50%;
}
```